# Pact JVM closeArray

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I  have problems with closeArray in pact-jvm-consumer.

Given Json like this, how would the 
"DslPart imeiResults = new PactDslJsonBody()"-statment be constructed.

```
{ 
   "Car": {
     "Price": 123,     
     "Features": [
         "rain sensor",
         "cruise control"
     ],
     "Id": "6500"
   }
}
```

I tried like this:

```
    DslPart etaResults = new PactDslJsonBody()
           .object("Car")
                .integerType("Price",123)
                .array("Features")
                    .stringValue("rain sensor")
                    .stringValue("cruise control")
                .closeArray()
                .stringValue("Id","6500")
            .closeObject()
            .asBody();
```

But that does not work, for example .closeArray() does not return PactDslJsonBody but DslPart, so you can never have anything after .closeArray()? I don't get it, can someone show the code on how to do this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess that your `stringValue` after the `closeArray` isn't working?

Sadly, when creating an array using the `array` function, it actually [creates a new `PactDslJsonArray` and when closing it, there's no way for that class to know what the parent is, hence it just returns the common superclass of DslPart](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-consumer/src/main/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/dsl/PactDslJsonBody.java), which can cause some confusion.  What needs to be done is cast that `DslPart` back to a `PactDslJsonBody` using the `asBody` function.  So, your example should be something like:

```
DslPart etaResults = new PactDslJsonBody()
   .object("Car")
        .integerType("Price",123)
        .array("Features")
            .stringValue("rain sensor")
            .stringValue("cruise control")
        .closeArray()
        .asBody()
        .stringValue("Id","6500")
    .closeObject();
```

Now, we know that this is confusing, [hence why we started working on a new DSL using Java 8's Lambda functions](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-java8) to try to make the experience better.  Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, I could get that example to work. But now I am stuck again. Ca you assist in creating a DslPart from this Json: 

{
    "Inventory": [
        {
            "Car": {
                "gearbox": "automatic",
                "ProductId": 30212
            },
            "Camera": {
                "EndPrice": 1235,                
                "Conditions": [
                    "FaultyButtons",
                    "FaultyCasing"
                ],
                "ModelId": "650"
            }
        }
    ],
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Info": "Ok"
}

Comment: What's the issue you're having?  I'm not keen on doing the work for you.  Please try and come back with an actual question.  Might be better to start a new question altogether.